# create a Groovy script distribution/executable via Maven

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have a project module full of groovy scripts which are run via embedded IntelliJ Groovy shell. In a new issue I need to have one of those scripts being run in combination with crontab. Needless to say I cannot just run `groovy myScript.groovy dev` to have this script executed out of the box - no the dependencies are missing for sure.

I now need a way to have this one particular groovy script being compiled and ready to run out of the box (with the use of the "dev" parameter)

Assuming that I put the **myScript.groovy** into a directory

```
main/
|_src/
  |_groovy/
```

What do I need to have a maven build creating a usable executable for me to drop into my machine and let crontab run it accordingly.

I tried a lot of Maven Plugins - but never came far enough. Also I'm sure that there must be a way more trivial way to achieve this since it's a simple build operation in my opinion.

Comment: How are you creating the distribution? Are you making an über-jar?

Comment: I'm about to drop the specific script I need in the main/src/groovy path. I don't want the other scripts to be packed as well.

Comment: But you'll need all the dependencies bundled as well; Groovy doesn't operate in a vacuum. Then you can follow a process roughly like http://stackoverflow.com/q/18255795/438992