# Running script from GMaven results in "No such property: project" exception

Tags: java, maven, groovy, gmaven

**tl;dr:** How can I resolve the "`No such property: project`" error when running a Groovy script from within Maven using GMaven? I'm using GMaven 1.5, Groovy 2.2.1. and Java 1.7, and Maven 3.1.0 .

---

I have a Groovy script -`DeltaCodeGen`(it has no package)- that generates Java code (for a Java project, this is the only Groovy in the project). It used to be that we would have the script generate the `.java` files and those would get checked in, but now we are trying to have them built during the Maven build during the [`generate-sources`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html#default_Lifecycle) phase.

I can run the script successfully from my IDE, but when I try to run it as part of my build I get

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: project for class: DeltaCodeGen
```

Despite [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527857/254477), my script does not have a variable called `project`, nor does contain the string "project" at all. It does not extend any other script. The only library it uses is [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) (the need for the Servlet API is still an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21054619/254477)).

Running build, I noticed in `stderr` (by running `mvn -X 2>mvn_err.log`) the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.v1_6.ProviderImpl.name(ProviderImpl.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.feature.support.ProviderSupport.asString(ProviderSupport.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.feature.support.ProviderSupport.toString(ProviderSupport.java:68)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.safeObjectAppend(MessageFormatter.java:304)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.deeplyAppendParameter(MessageFormatter.java:276)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:230)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(MessageFormatter.java:152)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.formatAndLog(SimpleLogger.java:414)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.debug(SimpleLogger.java:512)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.loader.DefaultProviderSelector.register(DefaultProviderSelector.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.loader.DefaultProviderSelector.select(DefaultProviderSelector.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.loader.DefaultProviderManager.select(DefaultProviderManager.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ProviderMojoSupport.provider(ProviderMojoSupport.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.feature(ComponentMojoSupport.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.feature(ComponentMojoSupport.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.doExecute(ComponentMojoSupport.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
```

---

My Maven configuration is:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- see: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-ExecuteaLocalGroovyScript -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/groovy/DeltaCodeGen.groovy</source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I finally got to work was replacing [GMaven](http://gmaven.codehaus.org/)(which is abandoned) with [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) (which is currently maintained).

Since running a local script isn't currently given as an [example](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples), this is what has worked for me in my POM:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scripts>
                    <script>file:/${pom.basedir}/src/main/groovy/DeltaCodeGen.groovy</script>
                </scripts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hello ArtB.. I was also having the similar problem as not able to access the pom properties in my groovy script. So, tries gmaven-plus as you'd suggested but still getting error while running script as (and accessing project property) like:
def String myProp = project.getProperty('myProp')


Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: System for class: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject

Comment: @Abhinav I'll help you with your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051201), no need to double post :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a wild stab in the dark but have you tried to bind the Maven "project" property to the script? In your original question someone suggested this by use of interpolation:

```
def project = ${project}
```

but that only works for inline scripts. In your case I would try

```xml
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/groovy/DeltaCodeGen.groovy</source>
                    <properties>
                        <project>${project}</project>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

Then you could probably put this in your actual groovy code:
project = properties['project']

I'm guessing that somehow the script runner is looking for a project member of your script where, of course, cmd line execution is not. So I would look toward defining or coercing the value.