# How access a variable with Groovy Plugin in Maven

Tags: reactjs, maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin, gmaven

I have an application with React in a children module and I'd like use the node.exe which exist in the parent module.

In Parent POM I defined a variable with path of the node.exe

```
<properties>
    <project.name>Corretor Online</project.name>
    <nodeBase>C:/col/COL</nodeBase>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

Obs.: I'd like to use ${project.basedir} in nodeBase Variable

And I try to access these variable in children POM to pass as parameter in ProcessBuilder method:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>webpack</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source><![CDATA[
                                println "Compiling client code..."
                                def webpack = new ProcessBuilder(["" + nodeBase + "/node/node", "" + nodeBase + "/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js", "-p", "&#45;&#45;progress", "&#45;&#45;bail"]).inheritIO().directory(project.getBasedir())
                                def env = webpack.environment()
                                env.put("WAR_NAME", project.build.finalName)
                                def proc_webpack = webpack.start()
                                proc_webpack.waitForOrKill(120000)
                                if(proc_webpack.exitValue() != 0)
                                    throw new org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException("Error compiling client code")
                            ]]></source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But I recive this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (webpack) on project col-backoffice-war: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nodeBase for class: script1539714060887 -> [Help 1]

And If I change from "nodeBase" to "${nodeBase}, I recive this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (webpack) on project col-backoffice-war: startup failed, script1539714572018.groovy: 2: unexpected char: '#' @ line 2, column 134.

However, If I put the literal path, I can build.

```
def webpack = new ProcessBuilder(["C:/col/COL/node/node", 
"C:/col/COL/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js", "-p", 
"&#45;&#45;progress", 
"&#45;&#45;bail"]).inheritIO().directory(project.getBasedir())
```

I couldn't find the solution for it, may you help with how I can access this variable?

Thanks very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051201/gmaven-plugin-how-to-set-property-in-pom-xml-for-external-groovy-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovey the problem.

It is necessary to put the parameter in quotation marks, like the example below.

```
    def webpack = new ProcessBuilder("${nodeBase}" + "/node/node", "C:/col/COL/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js", "-p", "&#45;&#45;progress", "&#45;&#45;bail"]).inheritIO().directory(project.getBasedir())
```